# Unknown component in rice cooker designated OS

Tags: components, identification

I am looking at the PCB inside of a Zoujirushi rice cooker, and there is a component that I can't identify. It has 3 wires and is designated "OS1". I couldn't find anything about an OS abbreviation online, but the neighboring component is labeled OS2 and appears to be a crystal.

The component is bright blue and the covering material is a rough ceramic. It has three wires and is placed next to the crystal below the LCD in the picture below:

[image: Zoujirushi rice cooker PCB]

Here is a closer look at it:

[image: closeup of mystery component]

The text on the component body appears to be "400C ~ 22.5" (hard to see because it's small and at an angle).

Note that the PCB is 2-sided, and all of logic stuff is on the other side. This side of the board is mostly controls, display, and power supply. Here's a picture of the other side:

[image: Logic side of the board]

The OS1 label appears in the lower right hand side of the large IC.

Comment: The presence of a crystal makes me think "oscillator" maybe?

Comment: Yep looks like a ceramic resonator to me

Comment: Omron, Panasonic, tdk in a rice cooker must a deluxe model

Comment: It's on the low end in Japan; new it was around 160 USD. This model is here: https://www.amazon.com/ZOJIRUSHI-microcomputer-cooker-extremely-NS-WF10-WB/dp/B002IT5V0A

Comment: I would hazard a guess (as it is in a rice cooker) that it may be **O**ven **S**ensor; as such it may be part of a thermally dependent circuit.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

OS stands for "Oscillator" in this case.

The pictured component OS1 is a 3-terminal ceramic resonator, such as this:

[image: Resonator]
<sup>[Image Source](http://uk.rs-online.com/web/p/ceramic-resonators/7926555/)</sup>

With the marking 400C it is probably a 4MHz frequency like the one pictured. This is a fairly standard frequency for cheap MCUs. The resonator will provide a clock to the microcontroller.

These resonators are very cheap parts which do not provide accurate timing (±1% is a typical accuracy). However in this application the frequency of the MCU is probably not all that important.

---

OS2 is a 32.768kHz crystal oscillator.

These are low frequency high accuracy crystals which are typically used for creating an accurate 1Hz (1 second) clock signal. The reason for the very precise frequency is that it is a power of 2 (2<sup>15</sup> to be exact) which makes dividing the frequency down to 1Hz very easy (using a simple free-running binary counter).

Additionally the circuitry required to run these low frequency crystals to get a 1Hz is very compact and low power, which makes it ideal for running off a battery like you would have in a watch.

In this example there is a small battery in the centre-left of the top image. When not supplied with an external power source, the rest of the circuitry will be powered down but the clock oscillator will keep going to keep track of what time it is.

Comment: That is fascinating! Thanks. Will upvote when I am allowed to again in 8 hours.

Comment: Specifically, it appears to me to be a Murata CTLSG resonator with built-in capacitors.  http://www.murata.com/en-us/products/timingdevice/ceralock/cstlsg

Comment: Concerning the battery: Is this really a non-rechargeable 3V lithium battery?

Comment: @Michael I'd presume so, but it's hard to tell from the photo. You can get rechargeable lithium coin cells, though the standard lithium manganese ones aren't.

Comment: @Michael Since it's a CR2450 I think it's a primary cell lithium battery. Most rechargeable button cells I've seen have another prefix, e.g. ML, LR, LIR, rather than CR.

Comment: Whatever circuit it is on probably draws so little current the shelf life of the battery is the limiting factor. (I would write may be but probably ... may be is illogical)

Comment: PC motherboard RTC backup cells are/were usually CR2032s.  They'd keep the clock running for a couple of years without power in my experience.  They were even used on PCs with real mains switching (XT/AT) in the days when machines were switched on for use and turned right off when not inuse.  A CR2450 has ~3x the capacity of a CR2032, but a rice cooker may well be unplugged more than a PC. (@Michael etc.)

Comment: @ChrisH: But the main difference here is that you can change the battery on mainboards and I’ve had a couple of older PCs where I had to do so.

Comment: @Michael yes, so I wonder if they expect you to keep this plugged in, or not care about losing the clock.

Comment: Yes, in a Japanese household you usually leave the cooker plugged in so you can start rice any time. Once in a while you will make rice and take it to an event and plug it in there. There is also a small amount of memory required, since it remembers your cooking settings and the current state (it should set to "keep warm" again automatically when you plug it in at your destination). I never used the clock to keep time; usually you use it only as a reference when setting the desired finish time. It is not backlit like microwave clocks, so you can't use it at night without a light.